# ICC, GCC and OpenMP

Tags: gcc, openmp, hpc, icc

I am launching a given problem that parallelizates by means of OpenMP. It runs a given number of iterations of the same piece of code that processes a volume of data. Is in that level where OpenMP is applied, making each thread process a subvolume. Every iteration should have the same workload, as well as every subvolume.

When compiled with ICC, iterations last always the same amount of time, as expected. But there comes the weird thing: when compiled with GCC, the time per iteration starts to increase, reaches a maximum and then decreases once again until it reaches a given value where it stabilises.  The same program compiled without OpenMP makes no difference when using ICC or GCC.

Does anyone observed that behaviour in OpenMP in those compilers?

[EDIT 1]: guided and static scheduling policies have been tested.

[EDIT 2]: The code looks somewhat like this:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(i,j,k)
 for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
       for(k = 0; k < N; k++){
            a[ k+j*N+i*NN] =  0.f;
            b[ k+j*N+i*NN] =  0.f;
            c[ k+j*N+i*NN] =  0.f;
            d[ k+j*N+i*NN] =  0.f;
  }
 for( t = 0; t  < T; t+=dt){
   /* ... change some discrete values in a,b,c .... */
   /*       and propagate changes                   */    
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(i,j,k)
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
          for(k = 0; k < N; k++){
            d[ k+j*N+i*NN ] = COMP( a,b,c,k+j*N+i*NN );
      }
  }
```

Where COMP performs some kind of linear application of values in a,b,c in the position k+j*N+i*NN (and some of their neighbours). The point is that this code in GCC and ICC caused the problem I described. The point is that I found out that I change the initialisation of a,b,c,d to some value other than 0.0f (f.ex, 0.5f) that thing that the time spent per time step increases doesn't occur.

[EDIT 3] : It seems is not GOMP's fault. The same happens with OpenMP disabled. Once again, with ICC (without or with openmp) doesn't occur at all. Is there any way I can close this thread?

Comment: Try to enable /for GCC and libgomp/ enviroment variables: `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0-31` where 31 is the number of cpu cores -1; and `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active` to get more predictable results.

Comment: Thank you! But I tried what your purposed and the behaviour persists. Could it be that OpenMP tries different chunsizes until it finds the optimal workload distribution? I didn't set any specific chunksize.

Comment: Can you show some model code which still has the same behaviour?

Comment: Showing us some code (including how you measure that behaviour) would really help. As another point: How long is your time per iteration and how much does the time per iteration change?

Answer (score 1):

May be, the COMP is doing *some* [denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) operations, which are done in software, not in hardware.

Working on denormals can vary the run time comparing with Flush-to-zero mode (when every denormals is rounded to zero). There will be more work to done in compiler which does denormals calculation fairly. And amount of work can vary between iterations.

*Intel Compiler* by default disables denormal operations and sets Flush-to-zero and Denormals-are-zero at any `-O` level (-O0, -O1, -O2, etc).

To turn denormals on, use: `-no-ftz` option of intel compiler [(docs1)](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/win/compiler_c/fpops/common/fpops_reduce_denorm.htm) [(docs2)](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/win/compiler_c/fpops/common/fpops_set_ftz_daz.htm#fpops_set_ftz_daz) or may be `-fp-model precise`

In *GCC* denormals-are-zero is turned only by  `-ffast-math` option, which is not set by any of `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`: [(grep a `-ffast-math`)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). The `-ffast-math` includes denormals ignoring [(bug36821,comment#1)](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36821)

So, if you have a lot of denormals in COMP, ICC will ignore them as zero, and GCC will doing a lot of software handling.

It is possible that denormals are not the case, but other floating-point handling difference is.

Comment: Thank you, but that was not the solution. In fact, it incremented the computation time, but without solving the problem.

Comment: What kind of operations are used in COMP? What is the CPU? Is there "turbo boost" or some powersaving in CPU? Is AVX used?

Comment: COMP just makes linear operations: multiplications and additions, everything in first order. In what concerns to the dynamic freq. in the cpu (I guess you meant that), I am not sure, I should take a look on that. And in what concerns AVX, I haven't introduced any kind of vectorization, only what the compiler does in O3, that is, using XXMS registers and instructions but only in the scalar way (I inspected the assembler code in order to check that).